# How to download PDF file on browser in Asp.net CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using below code which used to download SSRS report in pdf format:

```
 string URL = "http://ssrs-test.com/ReportS/?/UAT_FOLDER";
 URL = URL + "&SRNo=122&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=pdf";

 System.Net.HttpWebRequest Req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest) System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);

 Req.Method = "GET";
 string path = @ "E:\New folder\Test.pdf";
 System.Net.WebResponse objResponse = Req.GetResponse();
 System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
 System.IO.Stream stream = objResponse.GetResponseStream();
 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
 int len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);

 while (len > 0) {
  fs.Write(buf, 0, len);
  len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
 }
 stream.Close();
 fs.Close();
```

Which perfectly creates a pdf file in the specified path `E:\New folder\`, what I am trying to do is:

I need download it on browser as we were doing in the asp.net with `Response.Write()` and `Response.End()` etc.

Can I do the same in the ASP.Net Core?

What I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486431/return-pdf-to-the-browser-using-asp-net-core):

```
return new PhysicalFileResult(@"with_samplepdf_file", "application/pdf");  -- Not worked
```

---

```
var stream = new FileStream(@"with_samplepdf_file", FileMode.Open);
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");   -- Not worked - Nothing happening on the browser
```

---

```
var file = @"with_samplepdf_file/pdf";

// Response...
System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
   FileName = file,
   Inline = displayInline  // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
};
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file), "application/pdf");
```

Comment: If you want to display the PDF in the browser (as opposed to prompt to save it on disk) then the server-side code needs to specify a `Content-Disposition: Inline` header. See, for example, [ASP.Net Core Content-Disposition attachment/inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897764/asp-net-core-content-disposition-attachment-inline).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Tried this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38909848/7124761 but not happing anything on chrome

Comment: What kind of asp.net core project are you using? razor pages? mvc?

Comment: @Harry Its MVC..

Answer (score 8):

First,you need to be sure that you have uploaded the file in your project.

Here is a simple demo about how to download pdf on the browser in Asp.Net Core:

1.View:

```
<a asp-action="GetPdf" asp-controller="Users">Download</a>
```

2.Controller(be sure that the file have been exsit in `wwwroot/file` folder):

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult GetPdf()
 {
     string filePath = "~/file/test.pdf";
     Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
     return File(filePath, "application/pdf");           
 }
```

3.Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   //...
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   //...
}
```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible without storing the pdf in the project?

Comment: Only if make sure the file exsits on server you could find the file path and download it.

Comment: Can it be done with Stream? That means without storing file

Comment: Although it is done with stream,it also needs to exsits on server.

Answer (score 3):

I copied my pdf into the solution and changed the copy to output directory property to copy.

index.cshtml which **opens** the pdf in a browser tab:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<a href="/home/get">Open PDF</a>
```

index.cshtml which **downloads** the pdf to file system (include the download attribute on the html anchor tag):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<a href="/home/get" download>Download PDF</a>
```

home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var stream = new FileStream(@"example.pdf", FileMode.Open);
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: I m using AspNet Core, let me try this"

Comment: this is aspnet core

Comment: I don't why but not working am calling that get method as Ajax will that makes the difference?

Comment: with ajax the response is returned in your http response in javascript. You will need to use javascript to parse the response and cause the download manually. something like this https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/545/how-to-trigger-the-direct-download-of-a-pdf-with-javascript

Comment: actually maybe that links not good. i just searched for it quickly. maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999607/download-and-open-pdf-file-using-ajax

Comment: instead of using ajax why not create a hidden anchor tag in javascript and programmatically click it? ajax is normally for json/html text responses not file binary

Comment: Yes, using Ajax and Blob its downloing the file but the data is not in a proper format, will try with anchor tag

Comment: tried with anchor tag : It shows : `Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window with invalid URL 'http://localhost:57325/%PDF-`

Comment: don't use window.open, create a anchor tag programmatically and click it. something like this  `var anchor = document.createElement('a'); anchor.href = 'http://www.google.com'; anchor.click(); document.body.removeChild(anchor);`

Comment: Yes try this but its downloading the file but its show's: `Failed - no file` after download\

Comment: I think I am thinking in a wrong direction - I am calling an SSRS report as shown in the question, i need to download that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200646/discussion-between-prashant-pimpale-and-harry).

Answer (score 2):

You can download a three-way file.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var path = Path.Combine(
    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\images\\4.pdf");

    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
       await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;
    return File(memory, "application/pdf", "Demo.pdf");
}
```

HTML;

```
<form asp-controller="pdf" asp-action="Get" method="get">
  <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

[image]