# Return file as stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I need when client send the id of user ,  i return file for it as stream. File may be image, PDF, video or sound.

I'm using this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetAvatar(int id)
{
    var result = await mediator.Send(new FindUserWithIdCommand { userId = id });
    if (result.Success)
    {
        return uploadService.GetFileStream(result.Result.AvatarName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Upload service:

```
public FileStreamResult GetFileStream(string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        var stream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(finder.PathAvatarUserUploadFolder(), FileName));
        FileStreamResult file = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
        return file;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

but when i send a request for this action in postMan it show me this result:

[image: The result in post man]

Where's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is? You ask for a file and you get a file from what I see

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i need return file

Comment: And you get a file from what I see. So what exactly is not working here?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i need show file here and in browser but i download like a file and i need to go to the download folder and open it .

Comment: [What is the difference between inline and attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

Comment: @JohnWu can you edit my code for do this ??????

Comment: May be this can help:
[ASP.Net Core Content-Disposition attachment/inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897764/asp-net-core-content-disposition-attachment-inline)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what it is supposed to. What you're seeing is byte-code, because Postman doesn't support native rendering of things like PDFs. It *is* the file; it's just being displayed "raw".