# Downloading excel file - Norwegian characters are replaced with underscore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Trying to download an excel file from a .NET Core API.

```
var filename = doc.Name + Path.GetExtension(filePath);
// filename would be Name øæäåöõ.xlsx
var contentType = doc.ContentType;
return File(stream, contentType, filename, modifiedTime, null);
```

But the file is downloaded as Name ______.xlsx. The special characters are missing! Tried adding Content-Disposition from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51216687), but that didn't work either.

What am I missing here?

My response headers from Chrome:

[image]

Comment: There are two `filename` entries in the `Content-Disposition` header. Could you try to unescape the second with the UTF-8.

Comment: @burnsi OK, got it. I changed my code to `Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", attachment;filename=" + escapedFileName); return File(stream, contentType, modifiedTime, null);` and unescaped in the frontend! Thanks.